# Passing array values to separate method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

Read an array of 5 integer values in the main method. Create a separate function that will determine which number is the biggest. Return the biggest value to the main and print it within the main.
I started the code but my problem is that I do not know how to pass the values that I read in the main method (the array values) into the function! 
I started off like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class arraybiggest {
    public static int main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 values: ");
        int [] x = new int[5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            x[i] = in.nextInt();
            return x;
        }
    }
    public static int  passarray(int [ ] value) {

    }
}
```

Pls help me! Thanks!

Comment: Why is your main method returning int? Shouldn't it be void?

Comment: I guess this isnt the right place..

Answer (score 1):

You can just call your function and pass the array to it, like this:

```
passarray(x);
```

But first you need to remove the `return x;` from the loop.

Comment: Im still a beginner! So maybe what im doing is wrong. Can you correct the code and post it! Great help... Im trying so much but it is an error!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class arraybiggest {

   public static int main (String[]args) {
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter 5 values: ");
          int [] x = new int[5];
          for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
             x[i] = in.nextInt();           
         }

         int result = passarray(x);
         System.out.println("the biggest number is:" +result );
   }


  public static int  passarray(int [ ] value) {
        int result=value[0]
        for(int i=1;i<value.length;i++){
            if (value[i] > result) {
                result= value[i];
            }
        }
       return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        x[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
 passarray(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class arraybiggest {
        public static int main (String[]args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter 5 values: ");
            int [] x = new int[5];
            for (int i =0; i<5; i++) {
                x[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(findMax(x));
        }
        public static int  findMax(int [ ] value) {
            int max = value[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
                if (value[i] > max) {
                    max = value[i];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }

    }
```

Comment: i dont understand in:
 for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++) statement
what value.length is...

Comment: It's the size of the integer array 'value'.
'value' is basically integer array x.
Look at the line 'System.out.println(findMax(x));' in main - findMax(x) calls findMax with 'x' as value to the parameter called 'value'.